# Upload image with jQuery / Flash / HTML5

Tags: jquery, flash, html, file-upload, upload

Is there any upload tool or plugin that looks similar to the one that Codecanyon website uses to upload files ? I've already tried Uploadify, but it doesn't work on some browsers. I need something that works on all browsers, doesn't matter if its flash or HTML5 or anything else. Something easy to use. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), which is a flash based file uploader. It is NOT EXACTLY the same or like the one in Codecanyon. But it is highly customizable. Almost every aspect of Uploadify is fully customizable so you can create the uploader that suits your site perfectly.

You may also try [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), [SWFUpload jQuery Plugin](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/), [jqswfupload](http://www.alexandremagno.net/blogs/jqswfupload/), [jcUpload](http://www.jcupload.com/), [Flex Multi-file upload](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/flex-multi-file-upload) or [Flash Uploader](http://www.solmetra.com/en/disp.php/en_products/flash_uploader/uploader_intro).

Comment: I've already said in my post that I've used Uploadify before , I'm looking for something else