# upload image with flash or jQuery NOT UPLOADIFY

Tags: jquery, flash, html, file-upload, upload

I need something like plugin either jQuery or flash to let me upload images. But I don't want to use **Uploadify**.

I need something like below picture :

[image]

**Please don't suggest** **Uploadify** to me. I know that, but it doesn't work on all browsers. Any other plugin or tools ?

Comment: Please do not repost questions. What exactly is your problem with uploadify? There is no single uploading solution that will work on *all* computers. HTML 5 and Flash are not available everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload image with jQuery / Flash / HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921926/upload-image-with-jquery-flash-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) to work well for me. It has a good level of documentation, works with jQuery UI, and provides several options.